# Wordpress: filter posts by category in pages NOT WORKING?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, categories, posts

For over 3 days I am trying to filter posts in certain blog pages by certain categories on my wordpress theme: "Grafika".For example: I create a blog page called "Friends", after that I create a category named "friends" and after that I create 5 posts and I assign the "friends" category to those 5 posts.How can I do that on the "Friends" page to display only the posts from the category "friends".Currently the page shows all my blog posts from all pages.

I have tried many many plugins, query_posts, query_args, shortcut codes in page, modifying template.
Actually I have only 1 plugin wich almost fixed my problem.The plugin it's called "wp posts filter".But it doesn't fully work.The problem with this plugin is that I am applying a filter for Home Page and that filter goes to all my pages no matter that for other pages I applyied different filters.This is the plugin link: [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-posts-filter/)

Can somebody give me a REALLY WORKING solution to filter posts display by category on pages ? Thank you very much for reading !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) for your blog
2. Create a customized loop on this page http://pastebin.com/bRLhpGzC
3. change the page template to the one you created, https://i.stack.imgur.com/taqXt.jpg

Comment: This is my page template: http://pastebin.com/tqb2x2RK . How should I modify it ?

Comment: I believe that this commented part just before `get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );` is where you should replace with the code on line 16 to 23 in MY pastebin, uncomment the get_template_part function to so you can actually render content to the screen

Comment: try to remove the piece of code that loads posts that you don't want

Comment: I tried that, please look the result: http://prntscr.com/4mgt4u .This is how my page looks without deleting that data-path="...: http://prntscr.com/4mgter (This is how I would like to look, with 5 posts per row) but in this case the filter category doesn't work(all posts are displayed) and this is how my page looks if I remove that little code: http://prntscr.com/4mguf0 (on this screenshot, the category filter works but I don't like the stylesheet with 3 posts per row).Some suggestion ?

Comment: you can solve the 3 posts per row problem with css, or maybe taking a look at the loop file. In either case, it is no longer related with this question. I understand that your problem is solved then? you are now loading the posts filtered the way you want, now you need to solve a layout problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `functions.php` file of your theme, we can use the `pre_get_posts` function to alter the query before the page load.

```
function my_friends_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_page('friends')):
        $query->set( 'cat', 'friends' );
    endif;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_friends_category' );
```

This is assume the name of your page is `friends` otherwise replace it with the `id` of the page.

Comment: I just tried your fix but it didn't work.This is my page: http://www.zigzagprinromania.com/blog/?page_id=214 . Check this screenshot please: http://prntscr.com/4mfv1f .I want to display on that page only the posts marked with the "V" sign.The posts with the "V" sign belong to category named "parteneri".This is my page template: http://pastebin.com/tqb2x2RK

Comment: I tried your code like this: [code] function my_friends_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_page('214')):
        $query->set( 'cat', 'parteneri' );
    endif;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_parteneri_category' ); [code] .Where 214 is the id of the page and "parteneri" is the category from wich I want my posts to be displayed.

Comment: @ConstantinFlorinMinea You changed the name of the function that the add_action looks for to `my_parteneri_category` but you didn't change the function name to `my_parteneri_category($query)`.....please try again.

Comment: My bad, ok I just corrected it and it looks like in the following screenshot: http://prntscr.com/4mg22o .But it still won't work.Please check out my page template and look for a html comment wich says: The below code is the code wich display my posts on page... My page template: http://pastebin.com/aK3csGMN